# Java: G1 Old generation garbage collection count is 0

Tags: java, apache-kafka, garbage-collection, jconsole

We are setting up monitoring for GC for `Kafka`, which is running *Jolokia JMX* agent. 
We are using `Telegraph` to ship JMX out of the system to our `Grafana` servers for plotting the graph.

When we check the `G1 GC count for Old Generation` we can see that collection count and collection time is [image]

But the drop in memory pool for `G1 Old Gen` is evident in the following image [image]

The Java arguments for running the `Kafka` process by using the following command:

`-javaagent:/usr/lib/jolokia/jolokia-jvm-1.5.0-agent.jar -Xmx2G -Xms2G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xloggc:/home/test/kafka_2.12-1.0.1/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8000 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.31.24.149 -Dkafka.logs.dir=/home/test/kafka_2.12-1.0.1/bin/../logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./bin/../config/log4j.properties`

Can anybody point out the issue.

Answer (score 11):

G1 garbage collector utilizes 3 types of collections (all are Stop-the-World)

- young GC collects only young space
- mixer GC collects young space + few regions from old space
- full GC - emergency GC collecting whole things, it is triggered if incremental collection cannot keep up with application memory usage

Ideally full GC should never happen in G1.

Concerning JMX counters, 
 - young and mixer are counted as young GC
 - full GC is counted as old

As I said, in case of G1, old GC JMX counter is expected to stay at 0, though old space is reclaimed (incrementally) by young collections.

Comment: JMX doesn't provide different charts for mixer GC/full GC?